# How to update all entities at once - NGRX?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I need to update the `isExpanded` property in all entities.  I tried to do this with `reduce()` but got nested objects with `v` key :/

```
function updateAllIsExpanded(state, isExpanded): any {
  return Object.entries(state.entities).reduce(
    (p, [k, v]) => ({ ...p, [k]: { v, ...{ isExpanded } } }),
    {}
  );
}
```

In ngrx documentation we can find something like updateMany... but the problem is that I have to create arrays of objects with `id` and `change`... so I guess that's not a good idea ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ... in front of v:

**UPDATE:**

```
function updateAllIsExpanded(state, isExpanded): any {
  return Object.entries(state.entities).reduce(
    (p, [k, v]: [string, Object]) => ({ ...p, [k]: { ...v, ...{ isExpanded } } }),
    {}
  );
}
```

Comment: but then I will get error: `Spread types may only be created from object types.`

Comment: I updated it. Its a typescript check error. Is this working for you now?

Comment: great, it works but why in the redux tool I can see as many actions as I have edited entities? It looks like ngrx is registering additional actions due to changes in the store?

Comment: Its impossible to say what is happening in your case because we do not have a code :) It depends on few things, how your reducers, effects etc are organized, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for [`map`](https://v8.ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter#adapter-collection-methods).

> map: Update multiple entities in the collection by defining a map function, similar to Array.map.

```
adapter.map(
  (entity) => ({...entity, isExpanded }),
  state
);
```